# "The network path" and just "Path" or "A path"?

Tags: articles

This question is about filesystem paths and network paths only (computers)

I often see sentences such as *The network path was not found* or *...if path is not found..*

Confusion is regarding *The* and *A* word.

My understanding is if we don’t specify what kind of a path are we talking about then we should omit *The* and just say *path*?

And if we know this is network path or file path then we would use *The* and say *The network path* or *The file path*.

Assuming the *path* word is not used for the first time in some sentence otherwise we would say *A network path* or *A file path*?

I need help understanding when to say *The path* vs. *A path* vs just *path*.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the path is over a computer network or a local drive the idea of *path* is the same, though some will insist the details of a network make it much different. You are right that the initial use of "Network path" or "File path" will tell the reader which is being discussed. The paragraph will or should contain the details of said path and need not be repeated with every use. *The* path is *a* path is any path you like. The use of articles;"The" and "a" help to bring the noun out for examination, which is what the sentence is there for.

If two paths are being discussed it pays to clarify by pointing out which, if any, is looking over a network and which may be only local. If two paths of the same type are being bandied about you have a digital version of *Who's On First?* going and clarity becomes crucial. There are perfectly unclear sentences which are grammatically correct. More's the pity.

Comment: `The file path was not found, and every subsequent mention of the path means I'm talking about the network path. this is not a path here but the path because the path was already mentioned at least once?` Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Btw. to me it looks like I use `the` just too many times in the sentence above. should I replace some of the `the path` with just `path`?